# How to use spark to generate huge amount of random integers?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need lots of random numbers, one per line. The result should be something like this:

```
24324 24324
4234234 4234234
1310313 1310313
...
```

So I wrote this spark code (Sorry I'm new to Spark and scala):

```
import util.Random

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object RandomIntegerWriter {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: RandomIntegerWriter <num Integers> <outDir>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark RandomIntegerWriter")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val distData = spark.parallelize(Seq.fill(args(0).toInt)(Random.nextInt))
    distData.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Notes: Now I just want to generate one number per line.

But it seems that when number of numbers gets larger, the program will report an error. Any idea with this piece of code?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/48659259/462077 , you may find some more helpful answers there.

Answer (score 17):

In Spark 1.4 you can use the [DataFrame API](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/02/statistical-and-mathematical-functions-with-dataframes-in-spark.html) to do this:

```
In [1]: from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, randn
In [2]: # Create a DataFrame with one int column and 10 rows.
In [3]: df = sqlContext.range(0, 10)
In [4]: df.show()
+--+
|id|
+--+
| 0|
| 1|
| 2|
| 3|
| 4|
| 5|
| 6|
| 7|
| 8|
| 9|
+--+

In [4]: # Generate two other columns using uniform distribution and normal distribution.
In [5]: df.select("id", rand(seed=10).alias("uniform"), randn(seed=27).alias("normal")).show()
+--+-------------------+--------------------+
|id|            uniform|              normal|
+--+-------------------+--------------------+
| 0| 0.7224977951905031| -0.1875348803463305|
| 1| 0.2953174992603351|-0.26525647952450265|
| 2| 0.4536856090041318| -0.7195024130068081|
| 3| 0.9970412477032209|  0.5181478766595276|
| 4|0.19657711634539565|  0.7316273979766378|
| 5|0.48533720635534006| 0.07724879367590629|
| 6| 0.7369825278894753| -0.5462256961278941|
| 7| 0.5241113627472694| -0.2542275002421211|
| 8| 0.2977697066654349| -0.5752237580095868|
| 9| 0.5060159582230856|  1.0900096472044518|
+--+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: multiply by 10, 100, 1000 etc to get integers.

Answer (score 8):

try

```
val distData = spark.parallelize(Seq[Int](), numPartitions)
  .mapPartitions { _ => {
    (1 to recordsPerPartition).map{_ => Random.nextInt}.iterator
  }}
```

It will create an empty collection in driver side, but generate many random integers in worker side. Total number of records is: `numPartitions * recordsPerPartition`

Answer (score 4):

### Running on a Spark Cluster

The current version is materializing the collection of random numbers in the memory of the driver. If that collection is very large, the driver will run out of memory. Note that that version does not make use of Spark's processing capabilities as it's only using it to save the data after it's created.

Assuming we are working on a cluster, what we need to do is to distribute the work required to generate the data among the executors. One way of doing that would be transforming the original algorithm in a version that can work across the cluster by dividing the work among executors:

```
val numRecords:Int = ???
val partitions:Int = ???
val recordsPerPartition = numRecords / partitions // we are assuming here that numRecords is divisible by partitions, otherwise we need to compensate for the residual 

val seedRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq.fill(partitions)(recordsPerPartition),partitions)
val randomNrs = seedRdd.flatMap(records => Seq.fill(records)(Random.nextInt))
randomNrs.saveAsTextFile(...)
```

### Running on a single machine

If we don't have a cluster, and this is meant to run on a single machine, the question would be "why use Spark?". This random generator process is basically I/O bound and could be done in O(1) of memory by sequentially writing random numbers to a file.

```
import java.io._
def randomFileWriter(file:String, records:Long):Unit = {
    val pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)))
    def loop(count:Int):Unit = {
        if (count <= 0) () else {    
          pw.println(Random.nextInt)
          writeRandom(writer, count-1)
        }
    }
    loop(records)
    pw.close
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Working in Spark 2.3.0

```
Python  
df = spark.range(0, 10)

Scala
val df = spark.range(0, 10)
```

Comment: The question asks for random numbers, this will not give that.