# How to generate a DataFrame with random content and N rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I create a Spark DataFrame in Scala with 100 rows and 3 columns that have random integer values in range (1, 100)?

I know how to create a DataFrame manually, but I cannot automate it:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,20, 40), (60, 10, 80), (30, 15, 30))).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go, `Seq.fill` is your friend:

```
def randomInt1to100 = scala.util.Random.nextInt(100)+1

val df = sc.parallelize(
  Seq.fill(100){(randomInt1to100,randomInt1to100,randomInt1to100)}
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

Comment: When I test it with 50000 rows and add `.withColumn("id",monotonicallyIncreasingId)`, then `id` is created incorrectly. It arrives to 2000 and then it generates big numbers like `17179870015`. Do you know why?

Comment: @Markus this is how it works (read the docs). If you want an id from 1 to 50000 then use row_number (window-functions), but this is very inefficient.

Answer (score 12):

Generating the data locally and then parallelizing it is totally fine, especially if you don't have to generate a lot of data.

However, should you ever need to generate a huge dataset, you can alway implement an RDD that does this for you in parallel, as in the following example.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import org.apache.spark.{Partition, TaskContext}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

// Each random partition will hold `numValues` items
final class RandomPartition[A: ClassTag](val index: Int, numValues: Int, random: => A) extends Partition {
  def values: Iterator[A] = Iterator.fill(numValues)(random)
}

// The RDD will parallelize the workload across `numSlices`
final class RandomRDD[A: ClassTag](@transient private val sc: SparkContext, numSlices: Int, numValues: Int, random: => A) extends RDD[A](sc, deps = Seq.empty) {

  // Based on the item and executor count, determine how many values are
  // computed in each executor. Distribute the rest evenly (if any).
  private val valuesPerSlice = numValues / numSlices
  private val slicesWithExtraItem = numValues % numSlices

  // Just ask the partition for the data
  override def compute(split: Partition, context: TaskContext): Iterator[A] =
    split.asInstanceOf[RandomPartition[A]].values

  // Generate the partitions so that the load is as evenly spread as possible
  // e.g. 10 partition and 22 items -> 2 slices with 3 items and 8 slices with 2
  override protected def getPartitions: Array[Partition] =
    ((0 until slicesWithExtraItem).view.map(new RandomPartition[A](_, valuesPerSlice + 1, random)) ++
      (slicesWithExtraItem until numSlices).view.map(new RandomPartition[A](_, valuesPerSlice, random))).toArray

}
```

Once you have this you can use it passing your own random data generator to get an `RDD[Int]`

```
val rdd = new RandomRDD(spark.sparkContext, 10, 22, scala.util.Random.nextInt(100) + 1)
rdd.foreach(println)
/*
 * outputs:
 * 30
 * 86
 * 75
 * 20
 * ...
 */
```

or an `RDD[(Int, Int, Int)]`

```
def rand = scala.util.Random.nextInt(100) + 1
val rdd = new RandomRDD(spark.sparkContext, 10, 22, (rand, rand, rand))
rdd.foreach(println)
/*
 * outputs:
 * (33,22,15)
 * (65,24,64)
 * (41,81,44)
 * (58,7,18)
 * ...
 */
```

and of course you can wrap it in a `DataFrame` very easily as well:

```
spark.createDataFrame(rdd).show()
/*
 * outputs:
 * +---+---+---+
 * | _1| _2| _3|
 * +---+---+---+
 * |100| 48| 92|
 * | 34| 40| 30|
 * | 98| 63| 61|
 * | 95| 17| 63|
 * | 68| 31| 34|
 * .............
 */
```

Notice how in this case the generated data is different every time the `RDD`/`DataFrame` is acted upon. By changing the implementation of `RandomPartition` to actually store the values instead of generating them on the fly, you can have a stable set of random items, while still retaining the flexibility and scalability of this approach.

One nice property of the stateless approach is that you can generate huge dataset even locally. The following ran in a few seconds on my laptop:

```
new RandomRDD(spark.sparkContext, 10, Int.MaxValue, 42).count
// returns: 2147483647
```

Comment: This gives a `NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext`. AFAIKT, you cant just construct an RDD directly because it requires explicitly passing the SparkContext. When I try doing this in Notebooks it just works. Not sure what the diff is.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `scala.util.Random` to generate the *random numbers* within range and loop for 100 rows and finally use `createDataFrame` api

```
import scala.util.Random
val data = 1 to 100 map(x =>  (1+Random.nextInt(100), 1+Random.nextInt(100), 1+Random.nextInt(100)))

sqlContext.createDataFrame(data).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3").show(false)
```

Comment: It's not for Spark 2, right? How can I run `sqlContext.createDataFrame...` from shell?

Comment: You will have to create sqlContext for that. `val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this below generic code

```
//no of rows required
val rows = 15
//no of columns required
val cols = 10

val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("testApp")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val columns = 1 to cols map (i => "col" + i)

// create the DataFrame schema with these columns (in that order)
val schema = StructType(columns.map(StructField(_, IntegerType)))

val lstrows = Seq.fill(rows * cols)(Random.nextInt(100) + 1).grouped(cols).toList.map { x => Row(x: _*) }

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(lstrows)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a large amount of random data, Spark provides an object called RandomRDDs that can generate datasets filled with random numbers following a uniform, normal, or various other distributions.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html#random-data-generation

From their example:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs._

// Generate a random double RDD that contains 1 million i.i.d. values drawn from the
// standard normal distribution `N(0, 1)`, evenly distributed in 10 partitions.
val u = normalRDD(sc, 1000000L, 10)
// Apply a transform to get a random double RDD following `N(1, 4)`.
val v = u.map(x => 1.0 + 2.0 * x)
```